# Shift Excel Cell down after executing a macro for second time

Tags: vba, excel

I've written a (below)macro that pulls data from the sql server 2008 r2. My issue is when the user runs the macro for first time by entering Jobnumber (say J0001) excel puts data on the spreadsheet starting from cell "A1" which is fine. The issue here is, when the user runs the macro for the second time by entering the jobnumber (say J0002), excel puts the data for Jobnumber (J0002) on cell "A1" and shifts the cells for J0001(first job) to cell "F" instead of moving down. How can I shift the previous entry down in the spreadsheet with the latest entry on top?

Here is my macro and attachment:

```
Sub Task()
Dim sqlstring As String
Dim connstring As String
Dim Strcode As String
Strcode = Trim(InputBox("Please enter a Job #", "Task history"))
sqlstring = "select distinct m.JobNumber , cast(m.ExpectedDate as DATE) 'Ship Date' ,m.CustLongName 'Customer' & _
             " from ArchiveJobHeader m  left join AuxiliaryInfoFile af (nolock) on af.jobnumber=m.jobnumber & _
             " where m.JobNumber = '" & Trim(Strcode) & "'" & _
             " order by 'Resulttime'"
connstring = "ODBC;DSN=SQLDSN;UID=test;PWD=test123"
 Dim thisQT As QueryTable
 Set thisQT = ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=connstring, Destination:=Range("a1", "a1000"))
 thisQT.BackgroundQuery = False
 thisQT.Sql = sqlstring
thisQT.Refresh
End Sub][1]
```

Comment: This is what QueryTable does. When you Refresh it it replaces the old data with the new data (it refreshes!). What I really wonder about is why it does not overwrite the old data but moves it to a side? maybe it is because you Add yet a new QueryTable every time you run your code? Anyway, quit using QueryTables and just get query result into a recordset and write the records where you wish.

Comment: @GeneSkuratovsky - I'm new to Excel VBA. I would really appreciate, if you can help me with the recordset for my current Macro.

Comment: That happens because of this piece of code: Destination:=Range("a1"

Comment: what is going on at Range("A1000")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you incorporate a lastRow check and then assign a variable the Next Row number, you can concatenate your Range and it will be a new row every time.

```
Dim lastRow As Long, nextRow As Long

lastRow = Sheets("Sheet Name").Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
nextRow = lastRow + 1
```

Then when you set your Range, concatenate the variable with the string.

```
Set thisQT = ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add( _
                 Connection:=connstring, _
                 Destination:=Range("A" & nextRow))
```

I'm not sure what you are doing with row 1000 as shown in your question.  But this is the idea of using a variable with your normal Range Address.

Comment: @Gene Skuratovsky- Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You could have something like this:

```
Sub a()
'Must set Reference to "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library"
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim n As Long ' Row To Write In
    Dim sql As String
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim i As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tab Name")
    'Assuming you already have Headings in row 1 _
        and start adding records from "A2" down...
    n = ws.Range("A10000").End(xlUp).row + 1
    'you sql string above is missing some double quotes...
    sql = "select distinct m.JobNumber, cast(m.ExpectedDate as DATE) 'Ship Date', m.CustLongName 'Customer'" & _
             " from ArchiveJobHeader m  left join AuxiliaryInfoFile af (nolock) on af.jobnumber=m.jobnumber" & _
             " where m.JobNumber = '" & Trim(Strcode) & "'" & _
             " order by 'Resulttime'"
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    ' using an ODBC DSN... as in <http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms807027.aspx>
    cn.Open "SQLDSN", "test", "test123"
    Set rs = cn.Execute(sql) ' likely, in your case, to return one record only, _
                                so you are on there right away
    For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count
        ws.Cells(n, i + 1) = rs(i)
    Next
    rs.Close
    cn.Close
End Sub
```

You would need to put more work into this, I am afraid, but this is the direction you may consider.